# Is there a symbol for the sum of all possible 2nd order derivatives of a vector (analogous to $\nabla\cdot F(x,y)$ for 1st order derivatives)?

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors, partial-derivative, index-notation

I learnt that taking the divergence of a vector $F(x,y)=(F_x,F_y)$ gives a sum of first order partial derivatives:
$$
\nabla\cdot F = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y} )\cdot(F_x,F_y)=\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}.
$$

Is there a concise notation like the above to write the following sum of second order partial derivatives of a vector?
$$
\frac{\partial^2 F_x ^2}{\partial x^2 } + 
\frac{\partial^2 F_x F_y}{\partial x \partial y} +
\frac{\partial^2 F_y F_x}{\partial y \partial x} + 
\frac{\partial^2 F_y ^2}{\partial y^2 }
$$

I may have missed something trivial, but I could not find anything of the sort besides using summation indices:
$$
\Sigma_{ij} \frac{\partial^2 F_{ij}}{\partial i \partial j},
$$
where $i,j$ run over all possible choices of $x,y$.

Comment: Your second order operator is not at all standard. For starters it is nonlinear. There are a number of different second order differential operators for vector functions that have standard notation. But you can invent any operator you like as long as it is well defined. Perhaps a good place for you to start is the [vector Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian).

Comment: @epiliam thank you